# What is meant by Beamspace domain and antenna domain for channel matrix?

Tags: channel

I am not from Engineering background that's why asking these overly simplistic question. Anyone who can answer. These are basic research questions.
Thanks

Comment: Hi! Terminology depends of context. Where did you come across these terms, specifically (i.e. which publication/website/talk?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your response. Here is the link to the paper. They use both the terms in introduction. https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/12/4397